# Using String Interpolation and Fetch() to Make a Search Form Communicate with an API

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api, github-api

I have an issue with my program where I'm trying to use the github api to get github user information by searching for the users name. Some of the errors I'm getting repeatedly include:

Access to fetch at 'https://api.github.com/users/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
pull.js:7

GET https://api.github.com/users/ net::ERR_FAILED
getUser @ pull.js:7
oninput @ (index):17
pull.js:7

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at getUser (pull.js:7:11)
at HTMLInputElement.oninput ((index):17:101)

The details of the code I've done are below:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="flex justify-space">
<div class="text-space" id="scroll-container">
<ul id="note"> </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
const query_search = document.getElementById('search').value

const access_token = ''
const final_url = `https://api.github.com/users/${query_search}`

async function getUser() {
    await fetch(final_url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `token ${access_token}`,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'content-type'
        }
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => 
    document.getElementById('note').innerHTML = (data))
}
```

Comment: The server with the data has to put CORS permission headers on the response to grant the cross-origin JavaScript permission to read the data. It would be pointless if it was the other way around.

Comment: (And it makes no sense to stick a `Content-Type` header on a `GET` request - there is no request body to describe the type of.)

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the unnecessary headers, but I'm still getting an error: GET https://api.github.com/users/ 404 (Not Found). What could be the issue here?

Comment: I’ve solved the issue here by simply placing the variables in the function.